# Examples for failure of cohomology presheaf to be a sheaf

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map and $F$ a sheaf on $X$. Consider the cohomology presheaf on $Y$ defined by $V\mapsto \mathrm H(f^{-1}V;F)$. I am looking for some instructive examples to understand when:

1. The cohomology presheaf is *not* a sheaf.
2. The cohomology presheaf *is* is sheaf.

For the first question, I thought perhaps the sheaf condition might fail if there are several "local cocycles" which glue to a trivial cocycle, but I'm struggling with examples. At least in homology, it doesn't seem possible for local holes to exist without global ones.

Comment: $V\mapsto H^i(f^{-1}(V),F)$ is rarely a sheaf if $i>0$. In fact, it is never a (non trivial) sheaf if $f$ is the identity, and in that case, the sheafification is $0$ (and if $i=0$, it is a sheaf for any $f$). I don't know any interesting example for 2. (trivial examples are $Y=\{*\}$, or when $X$ is a vector bundle of $Y$ and $F$ is a constant sheaf).

Comment: Dear @Roland, I'm struggling with geometric intuition here. (My question is motivated by trying to understand the sheafification of this presheaf, which is the derived pushforward.) If the sheafification is zero (in particular noninjective) then compatible cocycles can glue to distinct cocycles. What are some simple pictures illustrating this? (You say the higher cohomologies are *never* sheaves.)

Comment: (I see formally why the sheafification is zero - it boils down to homology of an injective resolution whose higher cohomologies vanish. My problem is with the geometry and with the case where $f$ is a fiber bundle or submersion.)

Comment: Well, think about the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence : let $U,V$ be open subsets of $Y$ such that $U\cup V=Y$, then $f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V)=X$ and you have the long exact sequence with respect to the cover $f^{-1}(U), f^{-1}(V)$ : $$...\to H^{i-1}(f^{-1}(U\cap V),F) \to H^i(f^{-1}(Y),F)\to H^i(f^{-1}(U),F)\oplus H^i(f^{-1}(V),F)\to H^i(f^{-1}(U\cap V),F)\to ...$$You see in particular that if $H^{i-1}(f^{-1}(U\cap V),F)$ has a non trivial image in $H^i(f^{-1}(Y),F)$, the sheaf axiom for $H^i(f^{-1}(.),F)$ does not hold.

Comment: Dear @Roland, that is very instructive, thank you. The derived direct image $\mathrm Rf_\ast$ takes a sheaf $F$ to the sheafification of the presheaf $V\mapsto \mathrm H^\bullet(f^{-1}V,F)$. Proper base change identifies its stalks for nice $f$, but I'm not sure how to think of its sections in general. The sections of a sheafification are equivalence classes of compatible families that coincide eventually, so it seems $\mathrm Rf_\ast F(V)$ consists of equivalence classes of compatible families of cocycles locally on $f^{-1}V$?

Comment: Dear @Roland actually I'm even struggling with the geometric content of the vanishing sheafification of the cohomology presheaves: if $U\mapsto \mathrm H^\bullet (U,F)$ has zero sheafification then every cocycle admits an open cover on which it restricts to zero, right? So every cocycle is locally zero. On the other hand, consider the pushforward of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb Z}$ along $\mathbb C^\times \subset \mathbb C$: its first cohomology seems to also be $\mathbb Z$, but I don't see what open cover trivializes the cocycle. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see the contradiction here but maybe I don't understand the situation. $H^1(\mathbb{C}^*,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ indeed. A generating cocycle is trivialized by the open cover consisting of all open disks in $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: @Roland but when you push along $\mathbb C^\times \subset \mathbb C$ you have the origin too. How can the generating cycle for the pushforward be trivialized on any open neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: Sorry but can you give me exactly the cohomology group in question ? $H^1(\mathbb{C},j_*\mathbb{Z})=0$, $H^0(\mathbb{C},R^1j_*\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$,  $H^1(\mathbb{C},Rj_*\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: What to you mean by locally acyclic ? It may very well happen that for a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, there is no open cover $\{U_i\}$ such that for any $i$, $H^1(U_i,\mathcal{F})=0$. Take for example the Hawaiian circles and the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$. Or if you think the Hawaiian circles are pathological, then take the pushforward along the inclusion into $\mathbb{R}^2$. Oh, you removed your comment, well I let mine for now, I'll remove it later.

Comment: @Roland I think I don't understand the gap between being locally acyclic vs the cohomology presheaves having zero sheafification. The later means any cocycle is locally zero, and the former means there are locally no cocycles... (P.S thanks for your patience. I always learn a lot from you.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106874/discussion-between-roland-and-arrow).